# react-native-calendars landscape not aligned in android

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

`<View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}> <Agenda/> </View>`
im getting this problem in android, in ios it's working fine in android when i rotate  into landscape mode alignmet is not properly aligned.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iFkK.png)

What can be done to fix this Android alignment issue.